# Why would a recursive function be called on a pointer after NULL check?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

```
// So I call this function after deleting a node.
// It works before I delete the node, but for some reason
// after I perform a deletion and update the tree it runs into
// EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line below...

void BinaryTree::updateCost(BinaryNode *root) {
    if (root != NULL)
        root->updateCostRecursively(1);
}

void BinaryNode::updateCostRecursively(int newCost) {
    cout << this << endl; // prints 0x3000000000000000 before the bad access
    cost = newCost; // has a bad access here
    if (right != NULL)
        right->updateCostRecursively(newCost + 1);
    if (left != NULL)
        left->updateCostRecursively(newCost + 1);
}
```

Why is this recursive function called on the NULL object even when I check the pointer each time?

I have copied the code I use to delete a node below. I'm still having trouble understanding recursive functions, but from what can tell at no point am I leaving a dangling pointer.

```
BinaryNode *BinaryTree::findMin(BinaryNode *t) {
    if (t == NULL) return NULL;
    while (t->left != NULL) t = t->left;
    return t;
}

BinaryNode *BinaryTree::removeMin(BinaryNode *t) {
    if (t == NULL) return NULL;
    if (t->left != NULL)
        t->left = removeMin(t->left);
    else {
        BinaryNode *node = t;
        t = t->right;
        delete node;
    }
    return t;
}

bool BinaryTree::remove(int key) {
    if (root != NULL && remove(key, root))
        return true;
    return false;
}

BinaryNode *BinaryTree::remove(int x, BinaryNode *t) {
    if (t == NULL) return NULL;

    if (x < t->key)
        t->left = remove(x, t->left);
    else if (x > t->key)
        t->right = remove(x, t->right);
    else if (t->left != NULL && t->right != NULL) {
        // item x is found; t has two children
        t->key = findMin(t->right)->key;
        t->right = removeMin(t->right);
    } else { //t has only one child
        BinaryNode *node = t;       
        t = (t->left != NULL) ? t->left : t->right;
        delete node;
    }

    updateCost(root);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Because it's not NULL?  Note that `delete` does not modify the pointer.  If that's not the problem, then please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: 0x3000000000000000 != 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your delete method, not the code you posted. After you delete a node (say `root->right`) you need to set `root->right = NULL`. All you're doing with `delete` is freeing the memory that pointer points to. The pointer itself continues to point to that address. You're getting a bad access exception because you're trying to access the freed memory.

Comment: I have pasted the functions I use for deleting a node. From what I can tell I haven't left a dangling pointer sitting around, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @Yep: I suggest you step through your `remove` functions very carefully with a debugger, to confirm this one way or the other.

Comment: @Yep I'm sorry I don't have time to look closely at that code right now. At a glance it looks like you're going to have a dangling pointer if you delete a leaf.

Comment: Okay, I will attempt to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right spot, but I believe it was an issue with my destructor recursively deleting its children, which of course had terrible results.